# How to Dynamically show images from a folder in sdcard

Tags: android

I have to create a gridview that is loaded with images from a specific folder that resides on an SDCard. The path to the folder is "/sdcard/images/". i tried with this code,the app
 is taking too much time to load and it is displaying only one image.

```
    public class ImAdapterh extends BaseAdapter{

       File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myImages/");

int count=dir.list().length; 

String[] fileNames = dir.list();

 private Context mContext;

    public ImAdapterh(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = null;        


      for(String bitmapFileName : fileNames)
      {
           if (convertView == null) 
           {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
               imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
               imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
               imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
               imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);                   

               Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir.getPath() + "/" + bitmapFileName);
               System.out.println(dir);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
            }else 
            {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;            

            }
    } 
        return imageView;
        }
```

the app is taking too much time and it is displaying only one image

this is my activity class

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);        
       GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
       gridview.setAdapter(new ImAdapterh(this));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The path to the folder is "/sdcard/images/".

No, it is not, at least not for most devices. Never hard-code paths in Android. Always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of external storage.

> i tried with this code,the app is taking too much time to load and it is displaying only one image.

Of course. There is very little correct in what you have done here.

The biggest problem is that your `getView()` loads *every* image into the same `ImageView`, for each and every row returned by your `Adapter`. Presumably, you should be only loading *one* image into the `ImageView` for a given row.

Your next-biggest problem is that you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: @Kishore: I do not have "a sample code" for loading a directory full of images into an `AdapterView`. However, here is a free excerpt from one of my books that covers putting images in `ListView` rows that may help: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: Ware is there any other method insted of calling "getExternalStorageDirectory()" , in app to support Api 1.5+

Comment: @Kishore: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has existed since Android 1.0 (API Level 1).

Comment: ok sorry I was confused between getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: @Kishore: Ah, yes. `getExternalFilesDir()` is a fine choice for files that are unique to your app and should be removed when your app is uninstalled. However, that's pretty new.

Answer (score 0):

To get images from any specific directory. Use the following code

```
public void searchImageFromSpecificDirectory() {

        String path = null;

        String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        // if GetImageFromThisDirectory is the name of the directory from which image will be retrieved
        String condition = uri + " like '%/GetImageFromThisDirectory/%'";
        String[] projection = { uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };
        Vector additionalFiles = null;
        try {
            if (additionalFiles == null) {
                additionalFiles = new Vector<String>();
            }



            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    condition, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                boolean isDataPresent = cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (isDataPresent) {

                    do {

                        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(uri));
System.out.println("...path..."+path);
additionalFiles.add(path);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```